# Why does Aspect Fit add padding?

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, uikit

There isn't a height constraint on the following image and yet, with Aspect Fit mode, it adds padding to the top and bottom.

Why doesn't it align the image to the top and cut off the padding from the bottom? The green is a background added to the UIImageView.

[image]